# How can I set setTotalTimeout on SubscriptionAdminSettings?

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm having troubles with setting the totalTimout:

```java
SubscriptionAdminSettings.Builder subscriptionAdminSettingsBuilder =
        SubscriptionAdminSettings.newBuilder();
subscriptionAdminSettingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(() -> null);
subscriptionAdminSettingsBuilder
        .createSubscriptionSettings()
        .setRetrySettings(
                subscriptionAdminSettingsBuilder.createSubscriptionSettings().getRetrySettings().toBuilder()
                        .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                        .build());
SubscriptionAdminSettings subscriptionAdminSettings = subscriptionAdminSettingsBuilder.build();
System.out.println(subscriptionAdminSettings.getSubscriptionSettings().getRetrySettings().getMaxRetryDelay());
```

Output: `PT1M`

I tried a lot of combinations, it always stays at 1M. No way to change it.

As a side note: Using the spring boot starter it is locked at `PT10M`. So they somehow changed it.

Comment: So... The output is locked at 1m or 10m? It looks like you complain you can't change the 10m limit, but the output when you create a subscription is 1m...

Comment: @Jofre It's locked at 1m when I use the lib directly, locked at 10m when I use the spring boot starter

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the documentation](http://cloud/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions#retrypolicy) you can see that the maximum delay for retry policy is between 0 and 600 seconds so I believe that your code is working but the limit is 10 minutes not 30.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the value that you are setting. You are setting the total timeout field of the createSubscription request's retry settings, but fetching the max retry delay of the getSubscription request. You need to change your last line to:

```
System.out.println(subscriptionAdminSettings.createSubscriptionSettings().getRetrySettings().getTotalTimeout());
```

Then you will see that it indeed prints out 30S.